# SQL запрос на выборку диапазона даты и времени

Tags: mysql, sql

Имею таблицу вот такого вида:

[image: вид таблицы]

Не могу сделать выборку по дате и времени. Делаю так:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  HistoryReaders
WHERE
  (DateReaders BETWEEN "2018-08-30" AND "2018-08-31") OR
  (DateReaders = "2018-08-30" AND TimeReaders >= "04:00:00") AND
  (DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders <= "13:00:00")
```

Но выдаются значения только за последнюю дату.

Подскажите как правильней будет сделать запрос

Comment: так запрос правильно отрабатывает - во второй части условия `(DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders >= "04:00:00") AND (DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders <= "13:00:00")` вы выбираете только одну дату - 20180831. За какой период времени нужно выбрать данные?

Comment: Ну например диапазон дат 2018-08-30 и 2018-08-31.

Comment: тогда уберите вот это условие из запроса `(DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders >= "04:00:00") AND (DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders <= "13:00:00")`

Comment: либо же добавьте скобки, если хотите использовать `or`. Вот так - 
`SELECT * FROM HistoryReaders WHERE (DateReaders BETWEEN "2018-08-30" AND "2018-08-31") OR ((DateReaders = "2018-08-30" AND TimeReaders >= "04:00:00") AND (DateReaders = "2018-08-31" AND TimeReaders <= "13:00:00"))`

Comment: хотя, если честно, не понимаю смысла во второй части условия, т.к. оно в любом случае входит в первое...

Comment: это не подходит, у меня результат выдается со временем после 13:00:00(как в данном случае). А если я убираю эти доп условия то результат запроса выдает записи с 04:00:00 до 13:00:00 на каждую дату

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно выбирать по сумме даты и времени

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  HistoryReaders
WHERE
  (DateReaders BETWEEN "2018-08-30" AND "2018-08-31") AND
  (DateReaders + TimeReaders BETWEEN "2018-08-30 04:00:00"AND "2018-08-31 13:00:00")
```

Условие

```
(DateReaders BETWEEN "2018-08-30" AND "2018-08-31")
```

необходимо, чтобы изначально существенно ограничить выборку. Если у вас поле `DateReaders` индексировано, то вначале делаем быструю выборку по индексированному полю, а потом доуточняем ее.

Если же индекса по полю `DateReaders` нет, то и условие не нужно. В любом случае будет полный перебор записей

А вообще разделение полей даты и времени в 90% плохая архитектура. Если вам не нужны выборки за определенное время для каждого дня, то эти поля нужно объединить в одно поле типа `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: спасибо! Буду переделывать под TIMESTAMP

Comment: Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный (галочка под числом голосов)

Comment: Выбор по сумме полей таблицы == деградация производительности. Индексы-то идут лесом...

Comment: @Akina Да. Поэтому я и предложил вначале выбрать **только** по дате, или объединить поля